# How can I throw an error in JavaScript with trailing commas?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I know that `'use strict';` will throw some extra errors. However, they do not seem to include trailing commas.

I want something like the following to throw an error since I just spent several hours diagnosing failed poltergeist specs due to this. Firefox and Chrome do not have a problem with this.

```
function personRow(person) {
  $row = $('<tr>');
  person_url = 'https://directory.weill.cornell.edu/person/profile/' + person.weillCornellEduCWID;
  $row.append(
    $('<td>', { html: mailTo(person.mail) }),
    $('<td>', { html: phoneTo(person.telephoneNumber) }),
  )
  return $row;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

Comment: You can’t. Use a linter.

Comment: Yea for the most part trailing commas are legal code with a few exceptions.